# Batch processing an ArrayList with LongStream using Java 8

Tags: java-8

I am trying to process an ArrayList with content of Long type as in the given example below using Java 8's LongStream but I get the below error.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

 public class HelloWorld{
 public static void main(String []args){
    List<Long> data=new LinkedList();
     for(Long j=0L;j<300L;j++){
        data.add(j);
    }
   int BATCH = 10;

   LongStream.range(0, (data.size()+BATCH-1)/BATCH)
     .mapToLong(i -> data.subList(i*BATCH, Math.min(data.size(), (i+1)*BATCH)))
     .forEach(batch -> process(batch));
 }

static void process(List<Long> list){
     System.out.println(list);
 }
}
```

But I get the below exception. I have tried with mapToLong insted of map but mapToLong is not recognzied

```
$javac HelloWorld.java
 HelloWorld.java:13: error: incompatible types: possible lossy 
 conversion from long to int
     .map(i -> data.subList(i*BATCH, Math.min(data.size(), 
 (i+1)*BATCH)))
                             ^
HelloWorld.java:14: error: incompatible types: long cannot be 
converted to List<Long>
     .forEach(batch -> process(batch));
                               ^
 2 errors
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` in `LongStream` is supposed to map an element of the `LongStream` to a `long`, not to a `List`.

Use `mapToObj`:

```
LongStream.range(0, (data.size()+BATCH-1)/BATCH)
          .mapToObj(i -> data.subList((int)i*BATCH, (int)Math.min(data.size(), (i+1)*BATCH)))
          .forEach(batch -> process(batch));
```

Or:

```
IntStream.range(0, (data.size()+BATCH-1)/BATCH)
          .mapToObj(i -> data.subList(i*BATCH, Math.min(data.size(), (i+1)*BATCH)))
          .forEach(batch -> process(batch));
```

Comment: The solution worked thanks!.  Can I use LinkedList here as to maintain the insertion order of elements and in batch the order is maintained? or does ArrayList suffice?  Moreover I like to make it Synchronized to support multithreading

Comment: @Sawyer I don't see a reason to use a LinkedList, since it's less efficient (has no random access). ArrayList also maintains insertion order.

Comment: @Sawyer every `List` maintains the order, that’s the contract. Perhaps, you are confusing this with maps, i.e. the difference between `LinkedHashMap` and `HashMap`, but that does not apply to lists.

Comment: How can I make  changes to the above batch processing  such that the batch returns a list of id's it processed. Currently it is returning void for me

Comment: @Sawyer first of all, the `process` method would have to return a `List<Long>`. Then you can change `forEach(batch -> process(batch))` to `flatMap(batch -> process(batch).stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())`, which will result in a single `List<Long>` containing all the processed `Long`s.